# Ant produces jsfl with backslashes instead of slashes

Tags: ant, filepath, fdt

I'm using Ant with FDT 3 and I have Ant creating a jsfl to compile fla's. When I use the built in '${basedir}' property in Ant it gives me the path with backslashes(`\`) in it because I'm on Windows. The problem is that when its run through jsfl the slashes are taken as escapes. I need to know how to modify the basedir property so the slashes are converted to forward slashes. I've tried splitting the basedir on backslashes in jsfl and joining it with forward slashes as a delimiter, but the backslashes still cause problems.

So what I need to know is how to change the basedir in Ant to have forward slashes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the Ant [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task.

Here's a rough example:

```
<path id="basedir.path">
    <pathelement path="${basedir}" />
</path>
<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="basedir.unix" refid="basedir.path"/>
<echo message="${basedir.unix}" />
```

Then you can use `${basedir.unix}` in place of `${basedir}`.

Comment: You could also write the path conversion above as

<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="basedir.unix">
    <path location="${basedir}"/>
</pathconvert>