# How to "pathconvert" under Maven?

Tags: windows, maven-2, filepath

I am having a similar problem as [Ant produces jsfl with backslashes instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799684/ant-basedir-slashes-escape-problem) except that I'm running under Maven.

I'd like to generate cross-platform paths relative to Maven's built-in property ${basedir}. The problem is that under Windows, ${basedir} resolves to a path containing Windows-style slashes. Is there an easy way for me to get ${basedir} into a form that always uses Unix-style slashes even under Windows?

Comment: What is your use case exactly?

Comment: I want to pass a path that depends on ${basedir} into "java.library.path" but ${basedir} contains the wrong slash type under Windows.

Comment: I'm actually having a problem in that I need to pass in ${basedir}/passwordfile to maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin commands which the solutions below do not help with.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano I suggest posting a separate question and linking to the answers that didn't work for you (explain what actually happened).

Comment: Ya, I did find a solution already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Use `${file.separator}` instead of slash and watch out for bug MEXEC-81 which was fixed in 2010 by git commit [6e8be6881fe50714a00509f8f106e21d50d606a6](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/commit/6e8be6881fe50714a00509f8f106e21d50d606a6) (svn: 12372) which was where [quotes and backslashes](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Passing-basedir-into-Exec-plugin-td512272.html#a696586) were misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of adding a dir to the library path, you are better off creating a new artifact with its own pom, installing it in your local repo and adding it as a dependency in the project.

[Maven and Native Libraries: JDIC and java.library.path UPDATED](http://buildanddeploy.com/node/17) goes into more detail about getting a native dependency into the library path.

[Using native dependencies inside Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064045/using-native-dependencies-inside-maven) Is another approach.