# Using native dependencies inside Maven

Tags: maven-2, dependencies

A POM dependency contains native libraries (DLLs inside a JAR file). How do I programmatically look up the path of the downloaded JAR file so I can pass it into "java.library.path"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering my own question: http://web.archive.org/web/20120308042202/http://www.buildanddeploy.com/node/17

In short, you can use the maven-dependency-plugin:unpack goal to extract the libraries into a known path, and pass that into `java.library.path`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>org.jdesktop</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdic-native</artifactId>
            <version>${jdic.version}</version>
            <classifier>${build.type}</classifier>
            <type>jar</type>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @ksclarke, fixed. Thanks for the head's up. Please up-vote this answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Since `System.load()` can't load libraries from within a jar, you will have to use a custom loader which extracts the library to a temporary file at runtime. [Projects With JNI](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Projects+With+JNI) discusses this approach and provide code for the custom loader.

> #### Library loader
>
> We now have our JNI library on the
>   class path, so we need a way of
>   loading it. I created a separate
>   project which would extract JNI
>   libraries from the class path, then
>   load them. Find it at
>   http://opensource.mxtelecom.com/maven/repo/com/wapmx/native/mx-native-loader/1.2/.
>   This is added as a dependency to the
>   pom, obviously.
>
> To use it, call
>   `com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(libname)`.
>   More information is in the javadoc for
>   `NativeLoader`.
>
> I generally prefer to wrap such things
>   in a try/catch block, as follows:
>
> ```
> public class Sqrt {
>     static {
>         try {
>             NativeLoader.loadLibrary("sqrt");
>         } catch (Throwable e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             System.exit(1);
>         }
>     }
>     /* ... class body ... */
> }
> ```

An alternative would be to unpack the dependency, for example using [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven dependency plugin to copy the artifacts to a predefined path:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is inside the JAR, then you will need to copy it out to a directory before it can be loaded. (JARs that include native libraries usually do this themselves.) If your JAR isn't doing this, then you can use Class.getResourceAsStream() and write this to a directory that you've added to the `java.library.path`.

For an example of this, see [loadNativeLibrary](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.com/maven2/com.sun.jna/jna/3.0.5/com/sun/jna/Native.java#Native.getNativeLibraryResourcePath%28%29) in JNA. It uses this technique to load it's own library (a JNI library) from a JAR.

Comment: Great, but how do I do this from within Maven (as opposed to having to bootstrap inside my application code)?

Comment: I would advise against doing this in maven. If the JAR doesn't do it alaready, then create a simple companion JAR that does the unpacking - if your code loads the native library first, it will be found when the library JAR attempts to load the same library. The closest thing in maven is the dependency plugin, which can unpack a dependency to a directory. The native library will be there in the unpacked directory.