# install jar built from ant task into local maven repository

Tags: maven, ant, maven-ant-tasks

This is the command I want to run at the end of my Ant script:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\dev\common\somejar.jar -DgroupId=com.myco.gt -DartifactId=somejar-Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePOM=true
```

If I enter the following target at the end of my Ant script:

```
<target name='install_mvn_dependencies' depends='build_jars'>
    <exec executable="mvn">
        <arg value="install:install-file"/>
        <arg value="-Dfile=c:\dev\common\somejar.jar"/>
        <arg value ="-DgroupId=com.myco.gt"/>
        <arg value="-DartifactId=somejar"/>
        <arg value="-Dversion=1.2.0"/>
        <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar"/>
        <arg value="-DgeneratePOM=true"/>       
    </exec>   
</target>
```

I get `CreateProcess error=2. The system cannot find the path specified.`

even though I can run mvn on the command line.  What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mvn` command is actually a batch command, so you can't execute it directly. Try this:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="mvn.bat"/>
    <arg value="install:install-file"/>
    <arg value="-Dfile=c:\dev\common\somejar.jar"/>
    <arg value ="-DgroupId=com.myco.gt"/>
    <arg value="-DartifactId=somejar"/>
    <arg value="-Dversion=1.2.0"/>
    <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar"/>
    <arg value="-DgeneratePOM=true"/>       
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is ant / java, I would expect this: (untested!)

```
   <arg value="-Dfile=c:\\dev\\common\\somejar.jar"/>
```

Notice the double backslash, else it will be an escape and the path might not be found. 
IIRC you can also use forward slashes.

```
   <arg value="-Dfile=c:/dev/common/somejar.jar"/>
```

See also: [Ant produces jsfl with backslashes instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799684/ant-produces-jsfl-with-backslashes-instead-of-slashes)

Comment: Thanks for response but maven is not complaining that it cannot find the jar, which is the problem your proposed answer will fix.  Instead, Ant is complaining that it cannot find the mvn command.