# maven-antrun-plugin returns plugin does not found

Tags: maven, plugins, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I followed the post [install jar built from ant task into local maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629911/install-jar-built-from-ant-task-into-local-maven-repository)

I cannot figure out what is the problem, but this simply does not work. I do not know why they used `<arg value="mvn.bat"/>` instead of `<arg value="mvn "/>`
Anyway I have the following xml file:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>  
         <target name="mvn">
          <property environment="env" />
          <property name="appname" value="hellojavaworld" />
           <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
             <arg value="/c"/>
             <arg value="mvn "/>
             <arg value="install:install-file"/>
             <arg value="-Dfile=c:\Documents and Settings\bbb\workspace\HelloServlet\hellojavaworld\src\main\java\hellojavaworld.bin\hellojavaworld.jar"/>
             <arg value ="-DgroupId=${appname}"/>
             <arg value="-DartifactId=${appname}"/>
             <arg value="-Dversion=1.0"/>
             <arg value="-Dpackaging=jar"/>
             <arg value="-DgeneratePOM=true"/>  
           </exec>
         </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It returns errors:

> Error resolving version for plugin ' install:install-file -D
>   file=c' from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\bbb.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Comment: I think that problem is that -Dfile contains blanks on path and question is how to overcome it?

Comment: It seems that script above is correct,but the path is not properly recognized due to blanks. I tried to specify -Dfile path without blanks and has worked.

Comment: @Tunaki You are the man. Your solution works! I do not know what is the problem if there is a blank after mvn. Is there any possibility to display how the process is handled? I mean how it is translated and interpreted. The maven switch -X does not say so much information.

Comment: I added this as an answer since my guess was correct. Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very subtle and the error message doesn't help in this case.

The problem comes from the following configuration of the `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
<arg value="mvn "/>
```

It should be

```
<arg value="mvn"/>
```

The space at the end gets encoded to `%20` and this messes things up. I noticed it because when running your configuration, I saw the following log:

```
[exec] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/%20install/install-file%20-Dfile=c/maven-metadata.xml
```

Note that in this log, Maven is trying to look for `install-file%20` plugin, which obviously doesn't work.